# Adjective for "Cover up or conceal nefarious activity"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is an adjective describing behavior used to cover up or conceal nefarious activity, as in a "smoke screen"?
For example:

> His _____ nightly coughing fits were meant to drown out the rattle of the window opening as the girl crept in.

Comment: ...something like _distraction_ or _diversion_ , except they are nouns?

Comment: I've slightly altered your sample sentence, as I feel the adjective sounds more natural coming *before* "nightly". If you disagree, you can [edit] your question to change the word order. :-)

Comment: @Cascabel *distracting* or *diverting* would function as adjectives here... :-)

Comment: @Chappo My thought exactly... I was trying to get the OP to think outside of the box a little...

Comment: It seems that *deceitful* and *deceptive* would fit here,  but they are very broad compared to the narrowness of the question.

Comment: *Diversionary*.

Answer (score 1):

*"behavior used to cover up or conceal nefarious activity"*

"cunning" implies the use of artful deceit and seems like a good fit.

"His **cunning** coughing fits were meant to drown out the rattle of the window opening as the girl..."

> - **"cunning"** - adj.  crafty and shrewd, esp in deception; sly: cunning as a fox. [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cunning). Someone who is cunning has the ability to achieve things in a clever way, often by deceiving other people. [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cunning)

e.g.

- "The clever folk in management came up with a cunning plan."
- "Their cunning plan was to turn the by-election into a referendum on the EU."

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for one of two words, depending on the final lexical environment you go with.

As it is now, the best fit, I think, is *feigned*. 'His feigned nightly coughing fits...'

You might also use *ostensible*, but I usually encounter that one as an adverb, so you might reword slightly to fit convention.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

*His nightly (blank) coughing fits were meant to drown out the rattle of the window opening as the girl crept in.*

I would pose the word **[mask](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mask)** the following way:

> a fact, action, etc, that conceals something

As in:

She used his chronic coughing to **mask** the sounds of her entry into his room

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an adjective there, especially since you already have 'nightly' hanging about. Maybe you might consider ironing out the sentence a bit, like so—

> His coughing fits were meant to camouflage the rattling window as the
>   girl crept through.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted, with no explanation.  I guess maybe they weren't happy because you didn't include a definition and link.  Well, I upvoted -- I like *camouflage* and they didn't tell you how to fix your answer.  To edit your answer, click where it says "edit."

Comment: @aparente001 not my DV, but I'm guessing it's because the question asked for *Adjective for “Cover up or conceal nefarious activity”* and the answer fails to give one. It probably should have been a comment instead, and possibly should be closed as "Not An Answer". The DV could even be given as an objection to *camouflage*, which is an uncomfortable choice for disguising a sound.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that a guy sneaking a girl into his room is nefarious, which means evil or wicked. So I'll stick to your use case scenario.

> His **deceitful** nightly coughing fits were meant to drown out the rattle of the window opening as the girl crept in.
>
> His **misleading** nightly coughing fits were meant to drown out the rattle of the window opening as the girl crept in.

Also consider **devious**, **dramatic** and **theatrical**.